# Meaning of "having to sneak"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> One in ten has to "gear himself up" to rejoin hectic family life at the end of the working day and one quarter admit **having to sneak** in naps during week days in order to cope.

What is the meaning of *having to sneak*? Can this sentence can be said in some other way? Also, can you give another example where *having* is used like this?

Comment: Another way to say it might be: _one in four admit that they must sneak in a nap during the week_...

Comment: "one quarter admit they had to sneak in naps during week days in order to cope."

Comment: "Having to sneak" is plain English. [*Having*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have?q=having) + [*to sneak*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sneak?q=sneak).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Have to" is a Modal Verb that expresses necessity.

So in your example: the inserted "have to" makes your sentence mean that it's necessary for one to "sneak in naps" to deal with their hectic schedule.

But because the sentence is also using the Verb "admit,"

Admit + V+ing

We should say:

admit HAVING to sneak in naps

---

Another example would be:

I remember HAVING to attend choir practice when I was a kid.

Comment: IF This sentence can be express without Having then give  sentence without using HAVING

Comment: Certainly. "One quarter admit SNEAKING in naps during weekdays." Btw Pratik, you should practice using "please" in your requests

Comment: @Pratik pretend that your example sentence referred to just a single person (rather than one quarter of those polled) who *admits they **have to** sneak naps in during the week day in order to cope*.  For Cool Elf's example, he could have also said *I remember I had to attend choir practice when I was a kid*.

Comment: @Pratik: "have to" = "need to" or "must" (or maybe even "ought to", conversationally).  Some examples: _I **have to** go to the bathroom_ means _I **need to** go to the bathroom_.  _I **have to** go the bank before we go to the movie_ means _I **must go** to the bank before we go to the movie_. _It's getting late, I **have to** go home now_ means _It's getting late, I **ought to** head home now_. _You **have to** be starting to understand this now, right?_